Is each static library supposed to get its own copy of an inline variable?
It's supposed to be, according to info I've heard, that if you have a variable such as:
inline int a_var;

or
struct Foo
{
     static inline int a_var;
};

In a header file and include that header somewhere in a static library, library2, and then include that in a library, Library2, then each library will have its own copy of that variable.
So I tested this. I made an executable and linked to static Library 1 and static Library2.
I declare a variable in a struct in a common header:
struct MyStruct
{
    static inline int static_var = 0;
};

And in my executable/main() I do:
void library_one_function();
void library_two_function();

#include "common_header.h"
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    MyStruct::static_var = 1;
    std::cout << "Value from executable = " << MyStruct::static_var << "\n"; // I GET 1
    library_one_func(); // LIBRARY ONE FUNCTION CHANGES IT TO 7
    std::cout << "Value from executable = " << MyStruct::static_var << "\n"; // I GET 7
    library_two_function(); // LIBRARY TWO FUNCTION CHANGES IT TO 100
    std::cout << "Value from executable = " << MyStruct::static_var << "\n"; // I GET 100

}

Every single time I reference that variable there's no indication that each library has its own copy. It's always the same. Why is it then that people say that inline variables get their own copies?

Can you provide a reference to the "info I've heard"? Because I suspect that either you've misinterpreted it or it's just wrong.  Static data members of a class are shared by all instances of their class -- there is one associated with that class.

@JohnBollinger Hang on a second, maybe each static library gets its own copy, but when compiling the executable the compiler/linker only links one of them???

Haven't checked, but my guess is that, yes, each library has its own copy, but the linker picks one when you link your application. Each library has to have its own copy so that the library can be used by itself. Just like inline functions. And, further, it's probably every translation unit that use that header that gets a copy.

You should discriminate between the language semantics and the tools, formats, etc. by which those semantics are implemented.  Although C++ acknowledges that there may be separate compilation, libraries, and so forth, it does not license any of that to produce semantic or behavioral differences.

cppreference:inline "If an inline function or variable(since C++17) with external linkage is defined differently in different translation units, the program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required." - if the copies don't match, you may get shot in the foot.

@JohnBollinger "info I've heard" - Umm, in relation to a GUI library where there was a function called GetID() that had a counter - "As for the Raymond Chen quote. The way I interpret this, is that the compiler is free to actually inline the function. And in that case it looks like each binary will have their own copy of the static variable. But if it doesn't inline the function for any reason, e.g. take its pointer, then you will call RmlUi's copy of the function. I wonder for that reason, if there could be differences with debug vs release too, that is -Ob0 vs -Ob1."

@Zebrafish, that doesn't seem to be talking about the kind of constructs presented in your question.  Which is among the reasons why I asked for a reference, not (just) a quotation.

@teapot418 "is defined differently in different translation units, the program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required." - Theres no multiple definitions that are different, we're talking about a variable in a header that's defined the same. pasted into different static libraries, and in the end the executable.

My point is that there seems to be an expectation of merging the copies into one. Although this is the best evidence of that I found so far. So inline lets you do multiple definitions, but you still only get one variable in the end.

@JohnBollinger The topic was whether when you have getID() { static int counter = 0; return counter++;}  defined in a header would result in each static library having its own counter variable. I just tried this version with the counter and they all used the exact same copy. However I'm not sure if this is defined.

As I suspected.  That has to do with a static local variable of an inline function, not an inline variable.  And the answer there is definitely that regardless of whether the function is defined inline or not, all executions of it in the same program see the same static variable.

@teapot418 I knew that inline variables could be defined in multiple translation units and the compiler would select only one. But I assumed that that was PER library/executable. And that if you had multiple libraries executables there would be different ones that each uses.

@JohnBollinger What about in a dynamic library?

@PeteBecker "Haven't checked, but my guess is that, yes, each library has its own copy, but the linker picks one when you link your application." Right, can I assume this? I just want to know it's safe to continue on using inline variables. Let's just say my executable doesn't use the variable like in my example, but Library1 does in a function, and Library2 does in a function, I'm just wondering whether the final program will deduplicate them and make them one variable.

It does not matter, @Zebrafish. The C++ language specification defines the semantics of (well-formed) C++ programs.  Libraries of any variety are an implementation detail.  Conforming implementations provide the semantics required by the C++ specifications regardless of the involvement of libraries of various kinds, separate compilation, etc.

At least in Linux a static library is just a pile of object files. And it behaves like it. There is nothing special about static libraries that would provide a boundary different to just neighboring object files being linked. And I don't think the standard defines static libraries at all or any such boundary either.

@teapot418 Ah, I see what you're saying. I assumed that the deduplication happened among different translation units but not across libraries, or executable to library. But you're saying they're the same thing, an obj file is basically a static libary and so the linker uses the exact same rules.

@Zebrafish --it's the other way around: a static library is just a collection of object files. The main difference between linking a list of object files and linking a library is that the linker will link all of the listed objet files, but it will paw through the library to find object files that define the things it needs and only link those. But having identified all the object files that belong in the executable, all the object files are treated the same way, regardless of where they came from.

My experience is that dynamic libraries can indeed end up with multiple copies of a static variable.  Worst is when both a dynamic library and the main application use the same static library, because they both end up with copies of that library linked into them.


Is each static library supposed to get its own copy of an inline variable?

C++ doesn't say.
C++ does acknowledge the possibility of separate compilation and pre-compiled libraries, but it does not prescribe any details, and it does not allow for their use to affect the behavior or semantics of well-formed C++ programs.  The involvement and characteristics of libraries is an implementation detail that is not relevant to C++ semantics.
If, in a given implementation, multiple static libraries each got their own copies of static inline data members then it would be the responsibility of that implementation's linker to do whatever is needed to ensure that the C++ specification that ...

If a static data member is not declared thread_local
there is one copy of the data member that is shared by all the objects of the class.

(class.static.data; C23 11.4.9.3/1)
... is is satisfied.  That could be by merging multiple copies into one in some appropriate way, by refusing to link at all if there was a conflict, or perhaps by some other means.

Why is it then that people say that inline variables get their own copies?

Any well-informed people saying that and intending to be interpreted as you are doing, that such duplication could be visible within a C++ program, are remarking on possible avenues to implementation non-conformance.  That is unlikely to be observed with typical implementations of static libraries.  There is perhaps more risk with some implementations of shared libraries, but that is, again, an implementation detail.

Additional note
In comments, you quoted some remarks you attributed to Raymond Chen, regarding a different situation, about which you said:

The topic was whether when you have getID() { static int counter = 0; return counter++;} defined in a header would result in each static library having its own counter variable. I just tried this version with the counter and they all used the exact same copy. However I'm not sure if this is defined.

That pertains to a static local variable of an inline function, not a static inline variable as in the examples in your question.  In any case, although the spec may have been unclear about that at the time such an uncertainty was expressed, recent versions contain a note clarifying that (C++23 version):

Note 3 : An inline function or variable with external or module linkage can be defined in multiple translation
units (6.3), but is one entity with one address. A type or static variable defined in the body of such a function is
therefore a single entity.

(dcl.inline; C++23 9.2.8/6)
Thus the required semantics are analogous: there is only one copy of the static local variable as far as C++ behavior and semantics are concerned, whether the function is defined inline or not, regardless of how many or what kind of libraries are involved.

Additional additional note
You can, of course, simply avoid static inline data members, and perhaps also static local variables of inline functions.  Non-inline static data members (that are accessed) must have exactly one definition -- so not in a header -- and it is both necessary and relatively easy to ensure that that does not get duplicated.

Wow even something like that, whether statics in inline functions are considered one entity, wasn't clarified until C++23, interesting.

@Zebrafish The intent of letting inline on external objects was clear at the time of preposal. But std text is hard to read, and new comers - without historical background - make misinterpretations that require clarification and further patches in the std text. Informally inline keyword implies ODR-defined in header, but with external linkage. static keyword limits the linkage to internal, if used in namespace/global scope or in a function with internal linkage. The ambiguity of static keyword - with regards to surrounding scope - causes confusion.

@Zebrafish, I referred you to the clarifying note from C++23, but that form of the note first appears in C++17.  Versions at least as far back as C++11 have similar wording, but before C++17 it refered specifically to extern inline functions rather than inline functions with external linkage.  I think the latter is probably what was intended all along, but it's not what the spec actually said until C++17.
